# Privoxy templates and conditional logic

Tags: templates, privoxy

I'm reading through the Privoxy template documentation as well as reviewing the default template files and attempting to develop a custom header and footer that is included on all template pages without have to write the doctype and head parts on each template file. This is simple enough with the `#include <file here>` directive.

The problem with that is by doing that I then can't change parts like the `<title>` because its now included globally.

Does Privoxy offer a way to use the conditional logic or symbols to essentially to be able to determine what the current template page is and use this in code to conditional display certain values? As a basic plain English example:

```
# If browsing config.privoxy.org/ (root)
<!-- @if-default-page -->
<title>Specific title value for homepage</title>
<!-- if-default-page-end@ -->
```

I would also want to use this to conditionally display parts of code such as additional JavaScript when required.

Is this possible, does the functionality exist in Privoxy?